# A method that returns bool, but loads multiple objects

Tags: c#, java, oop, coding-style

I have a simple method that returns bool, but it internally loads various objects.

I check for null for each, but it becomes very ugly.

Is there a better way?

```
public bool SomeTest(int id1)
{
   bool result = false;

   User user = userDao.GetById(id1);

   if(user != null)
   {
      Blah blah = blahDao.GetById(user.BlahId);


     if(blah != null)
     {
         FooBar fb = fbDao.GetById(blah.FooBarId);

         if(fb != null)
         {
           // you_get_the_idea!

         }


     }
   }


   return result;
}
```

**Is there a pattern that could make this a more inline instead of nested if's?**

Comment: I always change VS to use 2 spaces instead of 4 for tabs.  This makes nesting less annoying.  I personally think what you have is closest to what you mean conceptually.  I.E., if this succeeded, then try this, if that succeeded.  The other option of having "return false" everywhere means there are actually implied "else"s nesting each of the following if's, and it could be more prone to problems if maintained/edited later by another developer.  It really depends on the context and complexity of what you are doing though, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 15):

Does it need to do anything other than check whether the entity exists? I'll assume not.

First step: ignore the "one exit point" rule and reduce nesting:

```
public bool SomeTest(int id1)
{
   User user = userDao.GetById(id1);    
   if (user == null)
   {
      return false;
   }

   Blah blah = blahDao.GetById(user.BlahId);
   if (blah == null)
   {
       return false;
   }

   FooBar fb = fbDao.GetById(blah.FooBarId);
   if (fb == null)
   {
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

What comes next is likely to be language-specific... what language are you using, and which version of the platform? Can you alter your DAOs? C# has a bit more language flexibility (lambda expressions, the null coalescing operator, things like that) which may be handy in this situation.

Comment: +1 for 'First step: ignore the "one exit point" rule and reduce nesting'
Some of the most unreadable code I've seen is done in the name of the one exit point rule :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there's nothing you can do to recover, you could just return as soon as you get a null:

```
User user = UserDAO.GetById(id1);

if(user == null) return false;

Blah blah = blahDao.GetById(user.BlahId);

if(blah == null) return false;
```

You might also want to look at the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Comment: +1 for the Null Object Pattern reference.  It may be very helpful depending upon the context of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

seriously?

```
Blah blah = GetBlah();
if (blah == null) return false;
```

Comment: There's no technical difference between this answer at -1 and Jon's at +7. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
User user;
Blah blah;
FooBar fb;
if( (user = userDao.GetById(id1)) != null
 && (blah = blahDao.GetById(user.BlahId)) != null
 && (fb   = fbDao.GetById(blah.FooBarId)) != null)
{
    // set flag, manipulate user/blah/fb, etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to all other answers, if you had an IDao interface for instance

```
public interface IDao
{
   bool CanGetUser(int id);
}
```

Then you can pass in a List of DAO's created somewhere else.

```
public bool SomeTest(int id1, IEnumerable<IDao> daoList)
{
   return daoList.Any( dao => dao.CanGetUser(id1) );
}
```